# Hidden friend idiom with templates

Tags: c++

Suppose that I'd like to write a compile-time string class:

```
template <int S>
struct String {
    // there is some char[S] data member here to store the string
    String(const char *s) { // copy 's' to the data member
    }
};

template <int S>
String(const char (&)[S]) -> String<S - 1>;
```

With this, I can write `String("hello")`, and a `String<5>` will be created, this is fine (the reason behind the `- 1` part is that I remove the trailing zero).

Now, I'd like to add a hidden friend `operator+` to concatenate two strings:

```
    template <int O>
    friend void operator+(const String<S> &, const String<O> &) {
        printf("lengths: %d %d\n", S, O);
        // some concatenation code here
    }
```

The problem is, this doesn't support concatenating a `String` and a string literal.

If I write this:

```
int main() {
    "hello" + String("!");
}
```

then `operator+` will be called with both operands having the length 1, as if the first operand had the same length as the second one ("1 1" will be printed as the lengths in `operator+`). The other variant doesn't compile:

```
int main() {
    String("hello") + "!"; // error: no match for 'operator+'
}
```

With non-template classes, the described technique works properly, there is no need to add additional overloads of `operator+`.  Is it possible to make this work in a simpler way than adding these two additional `operator+` overloads?

```
    template <int O>
    friend void operator+(const char(&)[O], const String<S> &) {
        printf("%d %d\n", O - 1, S);
    }
    template <int O>
    friend void operator+(const String<S> &, const char(&)[O]) {
        printf("%d %d\n", S, O - 1);
    }
```

Godbolt [link](https://godbolt.org/z/3c7jcPoef).

Bonus question: what if I wanted to write a hidden friend `concat` function, which can concatenate any number of `String`s and string literals (provided that at least one argument is a `String`). Is it possible to do?

---

Note: I think the reason that `"hello" + String("!")` calls operator with both operands having the length of 1 is that ADL will find `operator+` in `String<1>` (because `"hello"` won't be considered as `String<5>` when doing the ADL), so `S` will be `1`. And then `O` will also be deduced as 1.

Comment: *" Is it possible to make this work in a simpler way than adding these two additional operator+ overloads..."* **Why do you want to avoid writing two overloads?** It looks clear and simple enough imo.

Comment: @user12002570: no strong reasons. If I can avoid writing them, then I want to avoid writing them (just like the non-template case). If I cannot avoid then of course I'm going to write them. And maybe this problem is highly connected to my bonus question. Maybe it is not possible to implement `concat` without solving the `operator+` problem first. Another reason could be that I may have a class which has a lot more operators, not just `operator+`. I'd like to avoid adding overloads for each of them.

Comment: The friend is a red herring. This will not work either: `template <int S> void foo(const String<S>& s) {}; foo("abc");`

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI: it's an important aspect of the problem. The thing you mention doesn't work, that's right. But it can be easily transformed to a solution which works, like having a `template <typename>` kind of `foo`, which then SFINAE'd to only allow `String`s and literals. This can be done to a normal free function, but not to a hidden friend function, because ADL won't work.

Answer (score 1):

> Bonus question: what if I wanted to write a hidden friend concat function, which can **concatenate any number of Strings and string literals**

Yes, in c++20, you can use [user defined literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal) as shown below.  With this instead of writing `"hello"` we would write `"hello"_S`.

Note you can then add/concatenate arbitrary number of these things.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
template <std::size_t S>
struct String {
    String(const char *s):m_s{s} {
       // std::cout<< m_s << " \n";
    }
    const char * m_s;
    template <std::size_t O>
    friend String<S+O> operator+(const String<S> &s, const String<O> &) {
        std::cout << S << " " << O <<"\n";
        return String<S+O>(s.m_s);
    }

    
};

template <std::size_t S>
String(const char (&)[S]) -> String<S - 1>;

template<std::size_t N>
struct DoubleString
{
    std::array<char, N> arr;
    constexpr static std::size_t size = N;
    constexpr DoubleString(char const(&pp)[N]): arr("")
    {
         for(std::size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
         {
            arr[i] = pp[i];
         }
         //or with C++20 use std::copy which is constexpr instead of for loop
         /*std::copy(pp, pp + N, arr.begin());*/
    } 
};
 
template<DoubleString A>
constexpr String<A.size - 1> operator""_S() requires(A.size >=1)
{
   
    return String<A.size -1>(A.arr.data());
}

int main() {
     "hello"_S + String("!");      //prints 5 1
    String("hello") + "!"_S;       //prints 5 1
    "12"_S + "345"_S + "hello"_S ;   //prints 2 3 and then 5 5     
}
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/nT69K6vP7)

Comment: FWIW, `std::copy` is _constexpr_ in c++20. Could use it to replace the loop in the `DoubleString` ctor